# How to Animate Text in 3D Scatter Plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I would like to animate a 3D scatter plot where each data point has a text label that moves along with it.

Right now the text labels *do* follow the data points as I want, but they persist through each frame; the text does not disappear from the last animation update. See image below. The data points themselves are moving just fine.

2 Questions whose answers might help me >

1. Is there some way to clear the text without clearing the data points?
2. My implementation seems a bit clunky. Is there a hidden function similar to *_offset3d* that works for text objects.

Here's the **graphing function**:

```
def graph(data, update_cnt):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    dots = ax.scatter(data[0][0][:], data[1][0][:], data[2][0][:])
    dot_txt = nmp.ones(nmp.size(data,2), dtype=str)

    for n in range(0,nmp.size(data, 2)):
        dot_txt[n] = ax.text(data[0][0][n], data[1][0][n], data[2][0][n],'%s'%(n))

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, update_cnt, fargs=(dots, data, dot_txt, ax), interval=300)

    plt.show()
```

and the **animation update function**:

```
def update(num, dots, data, dot_txt, ax):
    y = data[0][num][:]
    x = data[1][num][:]
    z = data[2][num][:]

    dots._offsets3d = (x, y, z)
    #dot_txt._something_to_update_text_here()

    dot_txt = nmp.ones(nmp.size(data,2), dtype=str)
    for n in range(0,nmp.size(data, 2)):
        dot_txt[n] = ax.text(data[1][num][n], data[0][num][n], data[2][num][n],'%s'%(n))
```

and the current **plot output**:
[image: 3D scatter plot text animation attempt]

Comment: instead of adding SOLVED to the title of your question you must mark your answer as correct, that is the correct way to do it in SO, more details in [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I think it's important to note that I could not use the more common solutions for 3D animated scatter plots because I need different marker styles for various points. This forces me to iteratively plot each scatter point, rather than passing a list to the update function. However in doing so, the problem of animating the text is solved nicely.

**frame_list** contains the x,y,z coordinates and styling for each data point in every frame.

```
def graph(frame_list):

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

  frame_cnt = len(frame_list)

  ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frame_cnt,
        fargs=(frame_list, ax, frame_cnt), interval=600)

  plt.show()
```

The biggest contributor the success of this is the **ax.clear()** call before every frame.

```
def update_graph(f, frame_list, ax, cnt):

ax.clear()
f = nmp.mod(f, cnt)
frame = frame_list[f]

for n in range(len(frame.marker)):
    x, y, z, s, c, m, name = frame.get_params(n)

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=s, c=c, marker=m)
    ax.text(x, y, z, '%s'%(name))
```

The **get_params** function returns all of the relevant data for that frame.